# webservice invocation from webmethods Integration Server returns Cannot find dispatch method for {}

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, webmethods

I am trying to invoke a webservice from webmethods Integration server.
I imported the WSDL in my IS successfully, but when I invoke the webservice, I get this error :

```
Cannot find dispatch method for {}.
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does the WSDL look like?